# Consulta de datos

Tags: android

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, me encuentro realizando mi primera apps en android, anteriormente realice un programa a través de netbeans, con la base de datos mysql y ese mismo lo quiero llevar a android studio, realice mi primer crud completo y me funciona bien, pero me encontré con un pequeño problema que al ingresar los datos o modificar los datos a través de la api 28 o api 30 que es la última, me doy cuenta que los acentos y las ñ no funcionan en android pero en netbeans funcionan bien, acaso a hay que importar alguna librería que no se que exista, además adjunto una imagen para que vean el cambio sobre en el campo de descripción por ejemplo a lo que estoy diciendo con anterioridad, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: prueba con esta solución: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474591/8166997

Comment: A que te refieres con  "las ñ no funcionan en android pero en netbeans funcionan bien", en Android Studio o una aplicación?

Comment: buenas tardes de acuerdo a ,la imagen que se agrego en la consulta que al momento de ingresar o modificar datos como por ejemplo en la campo "Descripción", la palabra daños si te das cuenta no lo muestra como corresponde como en la fila anterior ingresada a través de netbeans y codificada a través e java

Comment: Ronquillo muchas gracias por el enlace, realice el ultimo cambio de compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1", sigue sin funcionar y con la api30 compilesdk, además te informo que en el mysql poseo el utf-8 unicode ci, el ccual se utiliza para que acepte la Ñ y los acentos.